# Execute multiple select query based on a query count output

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5

I want to execute the query the below "test" table only once. But I'm querying to check for the count and if the count is more than 1, then I need to execute another query.

Any leads on how to store test table result into a variable and then return from that variable to the function output so that I query the "test"table only once?

Below is an example, as my Prod table has millions of records and getting into performance  issue when I query multiple times :(

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcdm_main.test(IN p_member_crn character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(fname character varying, lname character varying) AS
$BODY$


DECLARE

countRow integer Default 0; 

BEGIN

PERFORM
t.fname, t.lastname
from test t where t.email =p_member_crn 
;

GET DIAGNOSTICS countRow := ROW_COUNT;

if countRow > 1 then 
 RETURN QUERY select concat( error_msg_cd , error_msg_nm )::character varying ,  NULL:: character varying
 from lcdm_main.error  where error_Cndtn_nm ='SMRF';

ELSE

return query
select
t.fname, t.lastname
from test t where t.email =p_member_crn 
;

END IF ;

END; 

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: Could you do a select-into a temp table and just use the temp table for the rest of the function?

Comment: Are you asking to create TEMP table to achieve this?

Comment: perform ...? GET DIAGNOSTICS ... ?  IF....?  why are you making that query extra unnecessary complex?

Comment: I made a function as an example to show, my actual code is a bit complex where multiple tables are joined. I suppose if I store the query resultset into a table type variable, unlike oracle we dont have variable.count to determine the number of records in variable. If I had one, then I would have avoided executing my complex query more than once for performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

Edit.

I might have misunderstood and miss some things at first.

According to your example, i assume that you don't care about precise record count on "test" query. You only need firstname and lastname if returned one record, or execute and return different query if test returns more than 1 records, right? so why don't you wrap "test" query with another one, limit result set to 2, add column count(*) over() to check whether recordcount is more than 1. Insert result into simple variables and then use IF structure to return variables or other query. Limit 2 might as well improve query performance on "test" query reducing amounts of joins made between rows if no ordering is done at the end of the query. This way you run test query only once, get necessary values and reduce resource footprint used by this function.  For example:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION lcdm_main.test(IN p_member_crn character varying)
  RETURNS TABLE(fname character varying, lname character varying) AS
$BODY$
declare

vfname text;
vlastname text;
countRow  integer;

BEGIN


 select q1.fname,q1.lastname, count(*) over() as cc
   from (
         select t.fname, t.lastname                                       
           from testq t 
          where t.email = p_member_crn limit 2 
        )q1

into vfname,vlastname,countRow;


if countRow > 1 then 
   RETURN QUERY select concat( error_msg_cd , error_msg_nm )::character varying ,  NULL:: character varying
   from lcdm_main.error  where error_Cndtn_nm ='SMRF';

ELSE

   fname := vfname;
   lname := vlastname;
   return next;

END IF ;


END; 

$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE SECURITY DEFINER
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

Comment: Thanks for your code.

However I want to either return a resultset from the test table or from the error table, but by executing test table only once(test is provided as an example, my actually code has multiple tables joined and millions of records exist)

Answer (score 0):

A similar question remain without a solution in below thread.

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/40214/postgresql-stored-procedure-to-return-rows-or-empty-set

Thanks everyone for different approach provided.